# Img source passed on prop to child component Vue Js

Tags: image, vue.js, components, react-props

So, i'm playing around with Vue Js and currently having some trouble on displaying an image on a child component, so, here i'ts what look like:

Parent component:

```
<list>
  <post name="post 1" image="somePath"/>
  <post name="post 2" image="somePath"/>
</list>
```

on the child component we got

```
<post>
 <p> {{name}} </p>
 <img src={{somePath}} />
</post>
```

I tried several ways with require, and other methods...
None of them have worked so far...
Any suggestions?
Also, here is how my img path looks like

```
"@/assets/web/mock/Phonebeats.png"
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just find out a way to do it! :)

Basically, on initial rendering, before vuejs got a chance to even render your code, the browser sees this:

```
<img src="{{ url }}" />
```

The browser then tries to load {{ url }} and fails with 404.
You need to use the new attr syntax (vue 1.0):

verbose

```
<img v-bind:src="url" />
```

shorthand

```
<img :src="url" />
```